# Linux: how to remove a partition from a volume?

Tags: linux, partitioning

When I recently installed Redhat onto my system, I had 2 hard drives in it, and apparently the default usage for the two hard drive is to put them all into 1 volume, so now I have files scattered across both hard drives (with boot on /dev/sdb).  LVM won't let me remove the /dev/sdb partition due to not enough room in volume or whatever.  What is the easiest way to shift everything, including the boot partition, onto one hard drive so I can remove the other one without reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 3):

I would say the easiest thing you can do is download [Gparted](http://www.gparted.org) and try all your resizing and partition editing through that.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get gparted